# Reactjs/Graphql: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

After selecting a date and time then clicking the submit button I get the following error:

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

The object is referring to is Action which is a query so I don't understand why it is saying it is not a function.  Also, please review handleSubmit event and ensure I am calling Action correctly. THanks!!

The render Component

```
class Calendar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputValue: ""
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(this.state.inputValue);
    this.setState({
      inputValue: new Date(document.getElementById("time").value).valueOf()
    });
    Action({
      variables: {
        timestamp: this.state.inputValue
      }
    });

    console.log(this.state.inputValue);
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div className="Calendar">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <label>Date/Time</label>
          <input type="datetime-local" id="time" step="1" />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
      //{this.render(){return (<UserList />)};
    );
  }
}

export default graphql(Action, {
  options: props => ({
    variables: {
      timestamp: props.inputValue
    }
  })
})(Calendar);
```

The Action query

```
const Action = gql`
  query($timestamp: Float!) {
    action(timestamp: $timestamp) {
      action
      timestamp
      object {
        filename
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct way of refetching the query.

Instead of

```
Action({
  variables: {
    timestamp: this.state.inputValue
  }
});
```

try

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(this.state.inputValue);
    this.setState({
      inputValue: new Date(document.getElementById("time").value).valueOf()
    }, () => {
      this.props.data.refetch({
        timestamp: +this.state.inputValue
      });
      console.log(this.state.inputValue);
    });
  };
```

if you don't want to call this props `data` you can rename it on your HOC `graphql`, like this:

```
export default graphql(Action, {
  name: 'WHATEVERNAME'
  options: props => ({
    variables: {
      timestamp: props.inputValue
    }
  })
})(Calendar);
```

then you would be calling `this.props.WHATEVERNAME` instead of `this.props.data`

hope it helps :D

by the way, you are binding your handleSubmit method 3 times. You need to do it only once:

1. binding in render is not advised because you would be processing the bind every rerender:

So you will probably want to change `<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>` to `<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>`

2. you can bind it on the constructor as you did. That is ok. But it is a little verbose. I would remove that.

3.`handleSubmit = event => {` by declaring the method as an arrow function as you did the method is automatically binded to `this`. So I would keep that and remove the other 2 :)

PS: note that on number 3 if you were to write `handleSubmit(e) {}` it would not be binded to `this` so you would need one of the other 2 approaches. But again, number 3 is the most efficient way to bind :) Just remove the other 2 and you are good to go.

Comment: Now I got this: `[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$timestamp" of required type "Float!" was not provided., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined` which is telling me that the timestamp value is not be passed to the query?

Comment: Notice this.props.data.refetch({timestamp}) gets the object with variables as a parameter. There is no need to declare `variables` as a key anymore like you were doing. Is it what you are doing ? Does your console.log prints the correct timestamp ? Try `+` before `this.state.inputValue` to convert it to integer, you are passing a date there. I will edit answer.

Comment: `export default graphql(getObjectsQuery, {
  options: (ownProps) => ({
    variables: {
      timestamp: ownProps.timestamp
    }
  })
}
)(Calendar);`

Comment: So how do I fix the above?

Comment: That part seems to be correct if you are importing `getObjectsQuery` correctly and if you are receiving timestamp as a prop ... I talking about the refetch, the syntax is a bit different

Comment: Are you getting an error on component mount or on handleSubmit ? You can do something like the following to help you debug

Comment: The format of inputValue is correct. I am having problems pass that value to timestamp when the submit button is pressed so the query can be executed with the value the user entered.

Comment: `export default graphql(getObjectsQuery, { options: (ownProps) => { console.log(ownProps.timestamp); return ({ variables: { timestamp: ownProps.timestamp } }) } } )(Calendar);`

Comment: You might want to call refetch query as a callback from setState ... since it is asynchronous, you are maybe calling the refetch query with the previous state, instead of the new one you want to.

Comment: Same error as before.  The inputValue is in the correct format but is not getting passed to the query.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this line: You might want to call refetch query as a callback from setState

Comment: Check back the suggested answer... just edited that :) 
besides that, can you place your new code somewhere I can take a look ?

Comment: Notice the refetch query is now inside a function callback sent as a second parameter to the setState function, this way I can guarantee I will have the updated value when I call `this.state`

Comment: I'm not seeing you use the data on your component... 
You will have to place it somewhere on your render function, like `{this.props.data.action.timestamp}` inside some HTML tag.

Comment: How do I run the query again but using timestamp?

Comment: `const getObjectsQuery =gql`
  query($timestamp: Float!){
    
    action(timestamp: $timestamp){
      action
      timestamp
      object{
      filename
      }
    }
  }

`;`

Comment: That's exactly what the refetch is doing ... check your network tab on chrome dev tools ... you must have made a new request on submit, using the timestamp