# Reacjs/Graphql: Pass variables values to query from event

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

So the code below is updating the state of inputValue but for some reason that value is not be passed to the query as the following error is shown:

[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$timestamp" of required type "Float!" was not provided., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined

So my question is how do I assign the inputValue to timestamp and pass timestamp to the getObjectsQuery?

```
class Calendar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputValue: ""
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(this.state.inputValue);
    this.setState({
      inputValue: new Date(document.getElementById("time").value).valueOf()
    }); //Parent component contains submit button and there lives state. Submit handler should only set value in state with...setState()- NOT directly
    this.props.data.refetch({
      //For some reason
      timestamp: this.state.inputvalue
    });

    console.log(this.state.inputValue);
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div className="Calendar">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <label>Date/Time</label>
          <input type="datetime-local" id="time" step="1" />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
      //{this.render(){return (<UserList />)};
    );
  }
}

export default graphql(getObjectsQuery, {
  options: props => ({
    variables: {
      timestamp: props.inputvalue
    }
  })
})(Calendar);
```

Comment: Please show you query

Comment: `const getObjectsQuery =gql`
  query($timestamp: Float!){
    
    action(timestamp: $timestamp){
      action
      timestamp
      object{
      filename
      }
    }
  }

`;`

Comment: have you checked the query is working correctly in graphiql/playground ?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's already solved in another place [Reactjs/Graphql: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51663433/reactjs-graphql-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function)

Just to remember (as you stil not learned):

```
handleSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  console.log(this.state.inputValue);  // OLD VALUE
  this.setState({
    inputValue: new Date(document.getElementById("time").value).valueOf()
  }); 

  this.props.data.refetch({
    //For some reason
    timestamp: this.state.inputvalue 
    // THERE IS STILL OLD VALUE 
    // because setState work asynchronously 
    // IT WILL BE UPDATED LATER
  });

  console.log(this.state.inputValue); // STILL OLD VALUE
};
```

To use value from event you could simply use its value, not passing it through 'async buffer' (state).

```
handleSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  console.log(this.state.inputValue);  // OLD VALUE
  const timestamp = new Date(document.getElementById("time").value).valueOf()
  console.log(timestamp);  // NEW VALUE

  // use new value directly
  this.props.data.refetch({
    timestamp: +timestamp
    // convert to int
  });

  // save in state - IF NEEDED at all
  this.setState({
    inputValue: timestamp
  });
};
```

Of course using setState callback is a quite good workaround, too.

Keep in ming that you can have 2 renders - one when state changes and second when data arrives. If storing value in state isn't really required you can avoid one unnecessary rendering.